# Applications of Pure Mathematics in Economics

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics

Are there any applications of number theory and abstract algebra in economics? An economist had told me that number theory had an application to a theorem in economics, however he did not remember what it is and my number theory professor in undergrad had also mentioned it but I can't find it. I know combinatorics and graph theory have applications in economics in regards to social networks. I am very curious about it

Comment: Fixed Points and Economic Equilibria by Ken Urai is a good book to know more about the abstract mathematical ideas behind economic theory. The author has talked a lot about Homology in this book.

Comment: I doubt you will find much use of number theory in economics. For abstract algebra, see for example [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03026639).